# sed replaces word boundary with two periods/fullstops

Tags: regex, sed

why would sed replace the word boundary with three periods/fullstops instead of  one?

`echo " 0/1:53,0,56:5:3,2    0/0:0,18,155:6:6,0 0/0:0,35,255:23:22,1" | sed 's/:[0-9,]\+\b/\./g'`

returns  `0/1...    0/0... 0/0...`

This happens even when I use `\>` instead of  `\b` for word boundary.

I'm running on
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-128-generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get multiple dots because you have `:` in the number sequence as well. Do this:

```
$ echo " 0/1:53,0,56:5:3,2    0/0:0,18,155:6:6,0 0/0:0,35,255:23:22,1" | sed 's/:[0-9,:]\+/./g'
 0/1.    0/0. 0/0.
```

In other words scan over `[0-9,:]\+` instead of `[0-9,]\+`. Also there is no need to escape the dot in the replacement part.

Comment: Ah. Thank you so much. I don't know why I hadn't caught that. Thank you for the explanation and solution.

Answer (score 2):

You want to remove all non-space chars after each `:`, so use `[^ ]*` POSIX BRE pattern instead of `[0-9,]\+`:

```sh
echo " 0/1:53,0,56:5:3,2    0/0:0,18,155:6:6,0 0/0:0,35,255:23:22,1" | \
 sed 's/:[^ ]*/./g'
# => 0/1.    0/0. 0/0.
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/ZNDXxd).

If there can be any whitespace, use `sed 's/:[^[:space:]]*/./g'`.

Note you do not need to escape the dot in the replacement pattern, it is a literal `.` char there.